# Syntax for constructor in template class

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a generic circular buffer template but there is some syntax error that I cannot understand.  The error is in my constructor, though it seems I've parameterized the destructor in the same way and that one works. I've followed the example in Stroustrup C++, and he uses a parameter before the scope resolution operator and also in the function name, just as I have.  I'm also certain there are no circular dependencies because I'm only compiling one file.  Also the implementation and declarations are in the same file (CircBuf.h) and there is no corresponding .cpp file, so linking should not be an issue either.  I've tried adding the "inline" keyword as per [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.2) solution and I get the same error.

```cpp
/* CircBuf.h */
template<typename T> class CircBuf {
  // don't use default ctor                                                                                                                                               
  CircBuf();

  int size;
  T *data;
public:
  CircBuf(int);
  ~CircBuf();
};

template<typename T> CircBuff<T>::CircBuf<T>(int i) {
  data = new T[i];
}
template<typename T> CircBuf<T>::~CircBuf<T>() {
  delete data;
}
```

makefile

```cpp
all:
        g++ -g -pedantic CircBuf.h -o prog
```

compiler-error

```cpp
CircBuf.h:13:22: error: ‘CircBuff’ does not name a type
```

Comment: You wrote `CircBuff` rather than `CircBuf` in one instance. This is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CircBuff` certainly does not name a type, the name of the type you intended is `CircBuf` with a single `f`.

Note that you also need to lose the trailing `<T>` on both constructor and destructor.

Comment: CircBuf.h:15:22: error: ‘CircBuf<T>::CircBuf’ names the constructor, not the type
CircBuf.h:15:22: error: and ‘CircBuf<T>’ has no template constructors

Comment: i removed the parameter from the function name like this and it works:    template<typename T> CircBuf<T>::CircBuf(int i)

Comment: @xst: the parameters at the constructor name are used when the constructor is a template as well.

Comment: @xst: this is a regular constructor of a template class `template<typename T> CircBuf<T>::CircBuf(int i)`; and this is a template constructor of a template class `template<typename T> template<typename U> CircBuf<T>::CircBuf<U>(U i)`.

Comment: OK thanks. btw, how did you markup the code in your comment. Also I tried using the @username and that won't show up.